# Use equations in blogdown in rmarkdown post

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I want to use equations in `Rmd` document, that represents post in `blogdown` blog.
When I use common approach for equations in rmarkdown:

```
$BDP = \sum S + \sum K + \sum D + \sum R + \sum A + \sum P$
```

it doesn't show equation on a blog (web page). Equation is displayed as::

```
\(BDP = \sum TroškoviRada + \sum Kamate + \sum Dividende + \sum Rente + \sum Amortizacija + \sum Profit\)
```

Why blog that is created using `blogdown` package doesn't "recognize" equation?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/36

Comment: I have to know html and javascript to do this? It looks complicated.

Comment: Ok. It's working now. thanks

Comment: @Mislav how did you get it to work?